# launch4j: Override Default JVM Heap Size via Command Line

Tags: java, heap-memory, command-line-arguments, launch4j

In the *launch4j* configuration for my Java application I have set values for the min. and max. heap size. This works fine, however, for some users it makes sense to override these parameters with other values. Is it possible with *launch4j* to have "default" settings for the min. and max. heap size, but still allow the user to override these settings via command line parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify memory settings in an .ini file next to the executable, however this will only work if you don't already specify memory inside the launch4j configuration.

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Runtime_options

Comment: Thanks, that might help in my situation. I will have a look at this option.